# How to encode stream of bits (not bytes) in Python - is any simple module for it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want encode and decode **variable** and **countable** stream of **bits** into **binary string**,  **number**, **64 bases encoded string**. Maximum length of stream will be about 21 + 20 = 41 bits but can be little longer 43, 45.

Let assume that bits will be represented by some array.

```
bits = [1]
encoded = someEncoder(bits)
decoded = someDecoder(encoded)
assert bits == decoded
```

The stream of bits can be longer for example:

```
import random

def generateRandomBits(l):
  bitsBytes = random.getrandbits(l)
  bits = []
  for i in range(l):
    bitsBytes
    bits.append(int(bitsBytes >> i & 1))
  return bits

bits = generateRandomBits(21)
# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Consider that it is **variable** list of bits and encode/decode must be **lossless**:

```
a = someEncoder([0])
b = someEncoder([0, 0])
assert a != b
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear. Do you want a string, a number, or a Base64-encoded representation? (In passing, the assertion in your first code snippet will fail since you're decoding `bits` instead of `encoded`).

Comment: it is clear - "or" means exactly "or" in this context I did not redefined it. I prefer binary string - It not matter since more important is algorithm idea than exact format. Not focus on silly mistake - sure should be encoded to pass assertion. Do you understand now or need some more explanation?

Comment: I am stabbing in the dark below; if my answer is not what you are looking for, you need to update your question to perhaps give some sample input and output.

Comment: Question is very clearly defined - all **bolds** is required **variable** and **countable** bits stream - code shows `bits == decode(encode(bits))` is common for encoder/decoder (png, wav but not for jpg, mp3). As I found you miss the last requirement if answer encode/decode so you understand it clearly except that should looseless encode/decode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments of @Martijn's answer I think you want the following.  This uses the idea of encoding a leading one to tell the difference between variable lengths of leading zeros:

```
import unittest
import itertools

def encode(bits):
    '''Encode n bits to an integer using a leading 1 to mark the length of the bit stream.

    Example: [0,0,0] == 0b1000 == 16
    '''
    # start with an initial 1.
    # iteratively shift current value left and OR in new bit.
    return reduce(lambda n,b: n << 1 | b,bits,1)

def decode(encoded):
    '''Decode a positive integer into a list of 0/1 values.
    The most significant bit marks the length and is removed.

    Example:  137 = 0b10001001 = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
    '''
    if encoded < 1:
        raise ValueError('encoded must be > 0')
    return [1 if c=='1' else 0 for c in format(encoded,'b')][1:]

class Cases(unittest.TestCase):
    def testEncodeZeros(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            bits = [0]*i
            self.assertEqual(encode(bits),2**i)
    def testEncodeOnes(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            bits = [1]*i
            self.assertEqual(encode(bits),2**(i+1)-1)
    def testDecodeZeros(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            encoded = 2**i
            self.assertEqual(decode(encoded),[0]*i)
    def testDecodeOnes(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            encoded = 2**(i+1)-1
            self.assertEqual(decode(encoded),[1]*i)
    def testEncodeDecode(self):
        for n in xrange(10):
            for bits in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=n):
                self.assertEqual(decode(encode(bits)),list(bits))
    def testDecodeZero(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError,decode,0)
    def testDecodeNegative(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError,decode,-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
testDecodeNegative (__main__.Cases) ... ok
testDecodeOnes (__main__.Cases) ... ok
testDecodeZero (__main__.Cases) ... ok
testDecodeZeros (__main__.Cases) ... ok
testEncodeDecode (__main__.Cases) ... ok
testEncodeOnes (__main__.Cases) ... ok
testEncodeZeros (__main__.Cases) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.041s

OK
>>> encode([0,0,0,0])
16
>>> decode(16)
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> encode([])
1
>>> decode(1)
[]
>>> encode([1,0,0,1])
25
>>> decode(25)
[1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> bin(25)
'0b11001'
>>> encode([0,0,0,1,0,0,1])
137
>>> bin(137)
'0b10001001'
>>> decode(137)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: You catch the heart of question clearly. Whatever @Martijn gives all the hits - now I have dillemma who should score. Your code is very good and very clear!+++

Comment: I give you usage of you can some dimensions with equal number of bits for example 3D limited tree (x, y, z) and you want to index space with codes to split it into large to small pieces. To do it you can mix significant bits from all dimension after normalization with different bits length depending on level of details. With this you can name each cube in space so it will easy index all object inside cubes with use code with different precision. Format of this codes can be designed in such way that first bits for parent will be similar like for children if parent aaa hild will be aaabcc aaabcc

Comment: Only one problem here `encode < 1` is bad - why `encode([0])` is `2` - border condition is different!

Comment: `[0]` encodes as `10` binary, or 2 decimal.  1 decimal decodes to zero bits or `[]`.  4 decimal (100 binary) decodes to `[0,0]`.  0 (or less) decimal has no meaning with this encoding scheme.

Comment: Now understand it clearly 1 is use for empty list []. It is the best solution of problem.

Answer (score 8):

To turn integers, representing bits, into 8-bit bytes (still as integers), use bit shifting:

```
result = 0
for bit in bits:
    result = result << 1 | bit
```

or with `reduce()`:

```
result = reduce(lambda n, b: n << 1 | b, bits)
```

This can be turned into a binary string with `format(result, 'b')`, optionally with width and `0` prefixed to pad with zeros to a certain length.

Demo:

```
>>> bits = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> reduce(lambda n, b: n << 1 | b, bits)
934809
>>> result = 0
>>> for bit in bits:
...     result = result << 1 | bit
... 
>>> result
934809
>>> format(result, '021b')
'011100100001110011001'
```

If you need to go straight to the binary string, just map the bits to strings and join:

```
>>> ''.join(map(str, bits))
'011100100001110011001'
```

Padding this further to 64 characters could be done with `str.zfill()`:

```
>>> ''.join(map(str, bits)).zfill(64)
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100100001110011001'
```

Comment: It is very good encoder. What about distinction 1-bits list from 3 or 41 bits list. List can be **variable** - decoder should encode **the same number of bits** without assumption about length.

Comment: @Chameleon: You mean you want it padded as a string to `len(bits)`? Then just use the map-and-join operation, leave out the `str.zfill()`; that already produces 21 bits, same as the input list length.

Comment: For example [0] will be encode into a and [0, 0] into b and a != b since it is different lists.

Comment: @Chameleon: Yes, sure, `''.join(map(str, bits))` produces the right length string in those cases. `'0'` and `'00'` respectively.

Comment: And for the one liner fan boys: `reduce(lambda fst, snd: fst << 1 | snd, bits, 0)`

Comment: @JonClements: The start isn't even needed, is it? If the first bit is `1` or `0` it'll do the right thing in both cases.

Comment: @Martijn Peters Sure ''.join(map(str, bits)) will work. I think about `result`.

Comment: @Chameleon: But what do you **need** as output, a string of zeros and ones, or an integer?

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope... but where `bits` is empty... your code leaves it as zero, while the `reduce` will `TypeError` without it... Depends whether it's an error, or zero in that case... I just mirrored your code...

Comment: @Martijn Peters Prefer integer or binary string. I think that length can be marked with `1` at start as you suggest - `0` will not work until start bits will be not filled will `1`. So I can to this in such way [0] will be [1, 0] and [0, 0] will be [1, 0, 0] same for other numbers. I think that is solution.

Comment: @Chameleon: You have now totally stopped making sense. The integer will use whatever bits you give it, but `[0, 0]` and `[0]` both are `0` as integer.

Comment: @JonClements One line is little crazy I will study this but not prefer such solution - I tell you why I have bad experience with it because it is not readable - good advice try avoid tricks as hell since after longer time studying your own code can be like hell. Little more lines can make any change and code improvement faster that is true speed and you happy. Whatever thanks for help I will check what it do.

Comment: @Chameleon hence the use of the term "fan boys" :)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters You not understand it should be `assert encode([0]) != encode([0, 0])` - integer is only medium to store bits. So as you suggets [0] can be 10b = 2L and [0, 0] can be 100b = 4 `assert 2 != 4`. [1, 0] can be 110b = 6L and so on ...

Comment: @JonClements Yeah as said that is for 'fan boys' one line after long time become 'hell cipher' I am using such for this style :) Whatever nice puzzle to study thanks.

Comment: @Martijn Peters fix `result` algorithm part for other people and I will score you points since your answer is very good but hidden in comments - lack of stop/start bit `1` to learn length.

Comment: @Chameleon: no, the leading `1` makes no sense *at all* because the integer result is no different. For input `[0, 1, 1]` the integer result is `3`, for `[1, 0, 1, 1]` and ignoring the leading `1` the result is *also* `3`; the leading `1` doesn't buy you anything. Besides, there is also `len(bits)` to tell you how many bits you have.

Comment: @Martijn, the leading one allows decoding to know how many bits are in the decoded result.  for 3, is it [1,1] or [0,0,1,1] or ?  Since the OP didn't post an encoded example it wasn't clear.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If we're actually talking about bits, `[1, 1]` is *exactly the same* as `[0, 0, 1, 1]` (they represent the same value). It may be the case the OP wants to store the information about those leading zeros, but then he wouldn't be encoding bits, but arbitrary lists of ones and zeros.

Comment: @Lukas Look at the OP's example.  `a = someEncoder([0])` vs. `b = someEncoder([0,0])`.  He does not want `a==b`.  He wants to encode "a variable and countable stream of bits".  So `[1,1]` and `[0,0,1,1]` are *not* exactly the same.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, his assertion is nonsensical in the context of bits representing values. If he wants to encode an arbitrary list of ones and zeros, that's fine, but he should word the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mark: So does `len(bits)`. It could be that the function should return bit count as well as the integer, but that doesn't require the leading `1` silliness.

Comment: @Martijn: From the OP's example, he wants `decoder(encoder(bitlist))` to return the original bitlist.  How will your decoder work for your 934809 example?  How many bits in the result?  The leading 1 "silliness" makes it possible.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: You cannot *have* that same result, because the leading zeros are not significant. Adding a leading 1 as signal bit is the wrong way of approaching this; why not have the function accept an expected bit size instead? How else would you represent an integer value as bits? I'd pad them after the fact to the desired width.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters It is need to generate unique code for different stream of bits with variable length. It is required `bits == decode(encode(bits))` by design. At program level is good to keep length in separate variable but at **storage** or **interchange** more important is to keep the simplest and smallest form as possible. What is simpler to tell `list [0, 0]` or 100b = `4` - it is clear that simpler and smaller `4` it is matter - at program level the best is [0, 0] and len([0, 0]) it is matter too. I think that explanation brings you much more understand.